# Play mp3 in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there some simple library to play mp3 files from Haskell? I need just to be able to play, pause and stop. Example code is welcome.

Comment: I don't know about a Haskell library, but when I was trying to do the same thing in C#, the simplest option was to use a command line player like mpg321 (see http://lindesk.com/2008/02/mpg123mpg321-the-command-line-mp3-players/ for an overview).  Otherwise, have you tried http://hackage.haskell.org?

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [sound libraries at Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Sound)